# Swift: Identify the entered characters are in ascending/descending sequence

Tags: swift

I have a textfield where i can't set the text which is ascending/descending sequence. like `"abcdefgh"` or `"1234567"`. how to identify the entered string is not in ascending/descending order in swift.

Comment: Helps to show what you have attempted and what's not working with it.

Comment: i tried to use swift filter but no luck.@MwcsMac

Comment: So you want a test that validates that the text a user enters is a sequential series of Unicode characters?

Comment: You should post the code that you tried, and tell us what worked/did not work about it.

Comment: You need to edit your question to clarify your requirements. There's lots of debate about what your question means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
enum Order {
    case ascending
    case descending
    case none
}

func getOrder(of text: String) -> Order {
    switch text {
    case String(text.sorted()):
        return .ascending
    case String(text.sorted().reversed()):
        return .descending
    default:
        return .none
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what the OP asked for, but I am sure that is what they really wanted. upvote, anyway.

Comment: The OP implied that they want to detect sequences of characters, not just that they are in ascending or descending order. The string "any" would return .ascending with your code, but is not a contiguous sequence of characters.

Comment: @DuncanC what Barns answered served my purpose. Can you pls upvote for this question.

Comment: @mokshaharish "upvote for this question? You mean give your question an up-vote? Hardly. It is unclear what you are asking, despite multiple people asking your to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Others have proposed sorting the string and checking to see if the array changes with sorting. That's not quite right, since the string "abcxyz" is in sorted order, but is not a sequence because it's missing some characters. Sorting is also relatively expensive, at least on larger arrays. (Not an issue if you're dealing with a few hundred characters, since a good sort algorithm's `O(n•log n)` performance is pretty much `O(n)` performance for small data-sets.)

How about this extension on String I came up with:

```
extension String {
    func isSequence() -> Bool
    {
        let charValues = Array(self.unicodeScalars).map { $0.value }
        guard let first = charValues.first,
            let last = charValues.last else { return false }

        return charValues == Array(first...last)
    }
}
```

It maps the string into an array of UTF32 values, and then checks to see if the result is the same as a range from `first...last` of the values.

You could use that function to validate a user's text input to see if it is a continuous sequence of characters like "abcdefg".

The above should have `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
func isOrderedSequence(_ string: String) -> Bool {
    return string == String(string.sorted())
}
```

Here are some test cases:

```
isOrderedSequence("1234567")  //true
isOrderedSequence("7836")     //false
isOrderedSequence("abcdefg")  //true
isOrderedSequence("Hello")    //false
isOrderedSequence("123abc")   //true
```

It uses [`sorted()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641066-sorted)

Comment: This is certainly what the OP asked for, but I am not sure that is what they really wanted. upvote for the answering correctly.  ::  I would be curious to know why someone would downvote this?!?

Comment: Actually that's NOT what the OP asked for. That makes sure that the characters entered are in order, but not that they are a contiguous sequence. That code would return `true` for the string "any". See my answer for a test that would only return `true` for a contiguous range of characters.

Comment: @DuncanC the question is not that clear, that's why it has had disparate interpretations

Comment: @DuncanC This is what i asked for. I don't understand why the people down voted for this?

Comment: @Carpsen90 what is not clear for you? This is about how to identify the ascending/descending character sequence and majority of they were proposed correct answers.

Comment: @mokshaharish Your question only gave examples of *contiguous* ascending sequences, so it wasn't clear whether you were looking for that specifically.  Would, for example, "abd" count for you?  That's why people were asking for more details in the question.

Comment: The string "any" is in an ascending order, but isn't in sequence. Should it pass your test? (letter 1, letter 14, letter 25.)